# how to read the current line and its preceding two lines using BufferedReader?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have a program lets say x that keeps on adding values to a .txt file using file.write().

And on the other hand i have a program that keeps on reading the currently added entry from the earlier .txt file.

But i want to read the current entry as well as the previous two entries .

Programmatically , Here is what i want.

```
for (100 iterations)
{
 prog named x ----> this code will enter a value to a .txt file and that too one entry per line.
 prog named y-----> this code will read the just entered value as well as the previous two entries , so all in all we will read three lines and do some computations based on these three values lets say we will take average.
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need to re-read those two previous values? Maybe you could simply remember them?

Comment: No,I want it the way described here in problem .

Answer (score 0):

Can you use one program with producer and consumer module to deal this issue?

thread X gets data and put them into a message FIFO, then write those data into a file, 
thread y get data from message FIFO and do some computation.

```
DataSource=>thread X=(message FIFO)=>thread Y

                   ||==>file on disk
```

I couldn't imagine how program X and program Y coordinate with each other to make sure program Y reads the newest data. Maybe use a counter to check entries.

Comment: yes i can use one program inclusive of everything.But how would this read the previous two values . Could you please explain it programmatically.

Comment: I saw you added java tag, can I use C# to write this program?

Comment: go ahead ,give it a shot